# Login Forwarding Page URL has too much info

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

In my MVC application, I am handling all of the login/authentication/etc myself, and have run into a problem. When a user access a page directly without logging in, I handle that with a LoginForward controller action. Here's exactly what I'm doing:

In many different Controller Actions (C#):

```
if (login == null)
    return RedirectToAction("LoginForward", "Account", 
        new ForwardViewModel { 
            ForwardToController = "Admin", 
            ForwardToAction = "ProxyMaint", 
            ForwardToID = id 
        });
```

The LoginForward Action (C#):

```
public ActionResult LoginForward(string ForwardToController, string ForwardToAction, int ForwardToID)
{
    return View(new ForwardViewModel
    {
        CurrentUserID = -1,
        ForwardToController = ForwardToController,
        ForwardToAction = ForwardToAction,
        ForwardToID = ForwardToID
    });
}
```

And in my View, after validating the login, I am doing this (javascript):

```
window.location.href = '@((Model.ForwardToID == -1) ? 
    Url.Action(Model.ForwardToAction, Model.ForwardToController) : 
    Url.Action(Model.ForwardToAction, Model.ForwardToController, new { 
        id = Model.ForwardToID 
    }))';
```

The problem I am seeing is that the view has a url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:66666/Account/LoginForward?ForwardToController=MyController&ForwardToAction=MyAction&ForwardToID=12345&CurrentUserID=0&CanAccessOpenItems=False&IsAdmin=False&CanAccessAnyReports=False&CanAccessAnyAdmin=False
```

Is there any way for me not to have all this data in my URL?

Comment: Just my two cents, but this is a whole lot of wheel reinventing as opposed to simply using the built in `[Authorize]` methods which also append a returnUrl parameter to redirect the user back to the page they requested before being asked to login.  As for your issue, unless you store those values in a cookie or session, there is not a lot of options to get that data to your login page.  Also, some of that data looks sensitive in your URL (such as IsAdmin, CanAccessReports).  I hope you are reverifying those attributes when that user gets to where they need to be going.

Comment: @Tommy It's a fairly complex app and I can't go back and force in the Authorize logic now. As for the sensitive data, none of it is ever populated, but is just a side effect of my ForwardViewModel extending my ViewModelBase, which has all of those fields. I suppose I could stop extending from ViewModelBase for that class (although it would be the only one), but even then I'd have those 3-4 properties in my URL that I do NOT want.

Comment: Not sure what your asking for. you want to keep the logic the same without changing your code, and just see if it possible to have the same url but to have it look nicer?

Comment: @Lupin I'd like for the URL to show something along the lines of: http://localhost:6666/Account/LoginForward only, and the additional data to not be exposed as it is.

Comment: without changing any thing in your code of the viewer & controller?

Comment: @Lupin I'm fine changing some code, but not rewriting the entire application to use the native Authorize filter(s) from MVC. I have already changed the ForwardViewModel to no longer extend my ViewModelBase class, so there are only 4 parameters in the URL now.

Comment: @ESDictor have you considered using rewrite rules or saving the data in the session before redirecting and then redirect to a clean url?

Comment: @Lupin I am thinking that's my only choice at this point